# Container does not get max width inside a Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `Container` widget inside a `Wrap` widget, and I want the `Container` to have the maximum width inside the `Wrap`, but when I use `width: double.infinity` for the width of the `Container`, it throws an error. How can I achieve my target? The code is below:

```
Container(
          width: 150,
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Text("Hi there!"),
              Text("This is a very long long string to show!"),
              Container(
                color: Colors.teal,
                height: 5,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
              Text("The end."),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a row to get full width

```
Container(
          width: 150,
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Text("Hi there!"),
              Text("This is a very long long string to show!"),
             Row(
               children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.teal,
                height: 5,
              ),
             ]),
              Text("The end."),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: The row widget is good for this purpose. The reason I use the Wrap widget instead is, that I want to have a fixed spacing between the elements of the Wrap using the Wrap spacing property, and with row I cannot do this.

Comment: You can add runSpacing to control space vertically between widgets

Comment: Yes I can do this. But using the Wrap widget causes the current problem that I asked the question about! A Container inside of it cannot get maximum width!

Comment: Well a container can he used in a full row in multiple ways. One way is to wrap it with a center widget

Answer (score 0):

You've define the top level width, To have the same width, you can just put it inside the container instead of adding widgets. like

```dart
Container(
          width: 150, //from here
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Text("Hi there!"),
              Text("This is a very long long string to show!"),
              Container(
                color: Colors.teal,
                height: 5,
                width: 150, //to here
              ),
              Text("The end."),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: The top width is added just for this example. Think the whole container is in Stack widget, which in that case it gets the whole width of the screen. I just want the inner container to get the width of the parent stack, not a hard-coded width.